# Pass an array from an Activity to a View Android

Tags: android, view, android-activity

I'm coding an app for android. How can I pass an int array from my activity to my view class? I've searched but not found anything that seems to answer my question. I have this class:

> public class ConvertToGrid extends Activity{...}

which takes the user's input from the Main activity's layout (using an intent) and converts it into an int array: `int[] binary = {...}` which has 64 values. How do I get it into this:

> public class DrawGrid extends View{...}

I naively tried an intent but unless I was doing it wrong, it seemed like the wrong thing to do for a view! Also, as an aside I assume I don't need to declare my View in the Manifest like I do my activities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a constructor that it has usual parameters plus int array,for example:

```
public class DrawGrid extends View {

    private int[] intArray;

    public DrawGrid(Context context,int[] intArray) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.intArray = intArray;
    }

    public DrawGrid(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle,int[] intArray) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.intArray = intArray;
    }

    public DrawGrid(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,int[] intArray) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.intArray = intArray;
    }


}
```

Comment: This seems like a great idea to me. I realise how basic my question was now.

Comment: Quick follow up, how do I then use the array I've passed in? I'm trying to refer to it later in my code but it complains that it doesn't know what 'intArray' is.

Comment: @David Please see my answer again.It is enough that create a field in your class and set it in constructors.

Comment: I realise now what I was doing, I needed to take my values from the array in the constructor otherwise they would be looking for the array before it was handed into the class.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public class ConvertToGrid extends Activity{.

Public int[] binary = {...}

public class DrawGrid extends View{...}

..}
```

Comment: It's probably better to encapsulate the data in the view (if it is using the data) than an activity. This way you can reuse it easily across different activities.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DrawGrid extends View{
int[] binary;

public void setBinaryData(int[] binary)
{
  this.binary = binary
}

}
```

Comment: Does this just make the int array publicly available to all classes in my project? Again, another very simple option.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a constructor that have param int[]

```
public DrawGrid(int[] binaries)
{
    // constructor
}
```